# How to map if a property has more information rather than primitive type?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to map if a property has more information rather than primitive type?

Example:

```
(Label :{ measured_depth: 'int'})
```

what if the `measured_depth` has unit system assigned to it (English) and unit code (ft).

Is it a feasible case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties can also contain more complex data structures called collections (similar to a python list) but not mappings (similar to python dictionaries). For your use case, you will probably need to create two different properties. For example, if you had a node with a property measured either in inches or centimetres you could store your data as a mapping like the below.

```
CREATE (n:SomeLabel {depth_val: 123, depth_unit: "cm", name: "Something"})
```

Although of course, you would probably want to parameterize that. You should also be aware of the `+=` operator, which allows you to assign all the properties of a mapping onto a node. I've provided an example as a parameter below.

If in the browser, you can set a parameter like the below:

```
:param measurement: {name:"Something", depth_val: 123, depth_unit: "cm"}
```

And then run the following. This will be equivalent to the first query.

```
CREATE (n:SomeLabel) SET n += $measurement
```

An alternative would be to store your values as a collection where the zeroth item was your value and the next item denoted the unit, however, since collections must store values of the same type, you would most likely have to devise some code using integers, which is far from ideal. If having too many properties might cause an issue (for example, if you have more than one measurement for each item), you could store each observation or measurement as a new node if needs be.

Comment: Certainly , this would be an elegant solution. However, properties cannot store collections. The first query in your answer (`CREATE`) results in the following error: "Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof".